# How to create an array with the results of an SQL query

Tags: python, sql, arrays, database

I am searching a table in a database and want to store all the results from ONE field in an array in python. I know this is fairly basic but I have no idea, please can you help me out?
this is the query which I want to store the results of in an array:

```
SQL = "SELECT day FROM tblBookings WHERE month = "'" + month + "'"
```

Comment: Which module for SQL are you using? Any code you have written at all? If so, please show it here, so people can see what you tried and where you failed. Otherwise this question will be considered: Wants us to write code for him/her, let's close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetchall()

```
cursor = connnect_db()

query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl`"

cursor.execute(query)

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

The variable result is an array so you need to do a for if you want to print the result

```
for row in result:
        print(row[0])
```

If you know you will receive only one row you can do :

```
print(result[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pymssql library:
More information you will find here:
http://www.pymssql.org/pymssql_examples.html#rows-as-dictionaries